# Unable to redirect to cart page from observer?

Tags: magento2, cart, event-observer, redirect

Here is the code, please review and advise.

> Demo/Test/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_generate_blocks_before">
        <observer name="Demo_check_for_vision_user_session" instance="Demo\Test\Observer\CheckForTestUserSession" />
    </event>    
</config>
```

> Demo/Test/Observer/CheckForTestUserSession.php

```
<?php

namespace Demo\Test\Observer;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;
/**
 * Class CheckForTestUserSession
 * @package Demo\Test\Observer
 */
class CheckForTestUserSession implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var SessionManagerInterface
     */
    private $coreSession;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @var Http
    */
    protected $request;

    /**
    * @var UrlInterface
    */
    protected $url;

    /**
    * @var ResponseFactory
    */
    protected $responseFactory;

    /**
    * @var RedirectInterface
    */
    protected $redirect;



    /**
     * constructor
     */
    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        SessionManagerInterface $coreSession,
        Http $request,
        UrlInterface $url,
        ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        RedirectInterface $redirect

    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->coreSession = $coreSession;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->url=$url;
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;

    }

    /**
     * Vision redirects a customer
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $action = $observer->getEvent()->getFullActionName();
        $SID= $this->request->getParam('SID');
        //$layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
        //$custId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP.'/var/log/magento11.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        if($SID){       

        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), 'checkout/cart');        
        }        
    }


}
```

Comment: Add this code in your execute and don't forget to return $this; in last. code : $url = $this->_urlInterface->getUrl('checkout/cart/index');
$observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);

Comment: No luck @RohanHapani which is throwing Call to a member function getResponse() on null

Comment: First, check that if condition execute or not. Put log in if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you are using "layout_generate_blocks_before" event to redirect to cart if current URL contains SID param. You can create a router file using following way.

> etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="redirect_if_sid" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Demo\Test\Controller\Router\RewriteSID</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Controller/Router/RewriteSID.php

```
<?php

namespace Demo\Test\Controller\Router;

class RewriteSID implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
{
    protected $actionFactory;
    protected $_response;
    protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->_response = $response;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $identifier = $request->getOriginalPathInfo();

        $condition = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(['identifier' => $identifier, 'continue' => true]);
        $identifier = $condition->getIdentifier();

        if ($condition->getRedirectUrl()) {
            $this->_response->setRedirect($condition->getRedirectUrl());
            $request->setDispatched(true);
            return $this->actionFactory->create('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Redirect');
        }

        if (!$condition->getContinue()) {
            return null;
        }

        if ($request->getParam('SID')) {
            $redirect_url = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('checkout/cart/index');
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

        $this->_response->setRedirect($redirect_url);
        $request->setDispatched(true);
        return $this->actionFactory->create('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Redirect');
    }
}
```

This will redirect any url to shopping cart page if URL is somewhat as below.

http://yourdomain.com/anyurl/?SID=1

Try this and i guess it can perform the same result.

Comment: Thanks @Yashshah i will check and let you know

Comment: I guess it worked for you. You can accept the answer if so. Also the previous one.

Comment: Hi @yash shah it seems cachable do you have any idea how to prevent. plz advise

Comment: @NagarajuK, i think routing has nothing to do with caching. and you have a pretty staright condition to chec SID. So no cache should play a role. If you can elaborate the issue in detail, it would be great.

Comment: Sure I will explain you actually the first time when i use http://127.0.0.1/magento2.3.1sampledata/?SID=value1  which is triggering 
2nd time when I use http://127.0.0.1/magento2.3.1sampledata/?SID=value2 on the same browser match method is not triggering even i tired with echo message and exit.

Comment: I have added this statement on di.xml file <argument name="cacheable" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument> it seems issue has been fixed let me check and keep you updated

Comment: Hi @yash I need your help here, actually, the user will redirect to M2 website from 3rd party with session id (param SID). i want to capture the SID and need to implement logic from my end. Can you suggest is this approach is correct

Comment: In the match function, if ($request->getParam('SID')) { you can anyways manage your logic what you want to do with SID.

Comment: could you please help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298536/magento-2-core-session-value-unable-fetch?noredirect=1#comment430232_298536

Answer (score 0):

You can change you Observer's code with below code

```
<?php

namespace Demo\Test\Observer;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;
/**
 * Class CheckForTestUserSession
 * @package Demo\Test\Observer
 */
class CheckForTestUserSession implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var SessionManagerInterface
     */
    private $coreSession;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @var Http
    */
    protected $request;

    /**
    * @var UrlInterface
    */
    protected $url;

    /**
    * @var ResponseFactory
    */
    protected $responseFactory;

    /**
    * @var RedirectInterface
    */
    protected $redirect;

    protected $_actionFlag;

    /**
     * constructor
     */
    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        SessionManagerInterface $coreSession,
        Http $request,
        UrlInterface $url,
        ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        RedirectInterface $redirect,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->coreSession = $coreSession;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->url=$url;
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
    }

    /**
     * Vision redirects a customer
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $action = $observer->getEvent()->getFullActionName();
        $SID= $this->request->getParam('SID');
        //$layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
        //$custId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP.'/var/log/magento11.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        if($SID){       

        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        $this->_redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), 'customer/account/create');
        }        
    }
}
```

I've added this line in your observer

```
$this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks @krishnan let me try and get back

Comment: but i am getting Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getResponse() on null in

Comment: Can you please check what you're getting here in this variable ?

$controller = $observer->getControllerAction();

Comment: Not getting any value @krishan savaliya

Comment: Can you please check your $observer's get_class_methods ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$redirectionUrl = $this->url->getUrl('checkout/cart');
$this->responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($redirectionUrl)->sendResponse();
```

Comment: @prince i have tried the above code but no luck

Comment: try to keep only my code inside `execute(Observer $observer)` and remove everything else

Comment: No luck @prince