# Magento 2 core session variable unable to fetch first time when user comes from 3rd party website

Tags: magento2, plugin, router, core-session

We have to fetch and set a session variable when the user redirects to our magento2 website using session-id from 3rd party site.

It looks like http://magento2.com/?SID=322e00bfqm3g6rfpjumah3939n

For this, we have written a custom router & match method but it's not triggering properly at the first time.

Could you please review the below logic and files and advise please.

**Note**: The implementation is in the same module only.
 The concept of this implementation is if the user redirecting to the M2 website from 3rd party we need to save fetch the SID (session-id) & and the user will browse the products on the M2 website. who are coming from 3rd party we don't want to display proceed to checkout button.

I have written a custom router and setting array value in the core session and trying to fetch that value in the plugin which is in the same module.

> 1. app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="redirect_if_sid" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Router\RewriteSID</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="cacheable" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <! -- For Proceed to checkout button -->
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data">
        <plugin name="CartPageProceeedtoToCheckoutButton" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\AfterProceedToCheckoutButton" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> 2. Vendor/ModuleName/Controller/Router/RewriteSID.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Router;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
class RewriteSID implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
{   

    private $logger;
    private $actionFactory;
    private $response;
    private $formKey; 
    private $coreSession;    

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        ActionFactory $actionFactory,
        ResponseInterface $response,
        FormKey $formKey,
        SessionManagerInterface $coreSession

    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->response = $response;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->coreSession = $coreSession;

    }

    public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $identifier = $request->getOriginalPathInfo();
        $condition = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(['identifier' => $identifier, 'continue' => true]);
        $identifier = $condition->getIdentifier();
        if ($condition->getRedirectUrl()) {
            $this->response->setRedirect($condition->getRedirectUrl());
            $request->setDispatched(true);
            return $this->actionFactory->create('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Redirect');
        }
        if (!$condition->getContinue()) {
            return null;
        }
        if ($request->getParam('SID')) {

            $sessionData = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
           try {  
                    $this->coreSession->setVIEUserData($sessionData);
            }catch(\Exception $e) {
                    $this->logger->info("Something went wrong");
                    $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
            }

        }//get params ends here
        else
        {
            return null;
        }  
    }

}
```

> 3. app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Plugin/AfterProceedToCheckoutButton.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager;
class AfterProceedToCheckoutButton
{


    private $coreSession;

    public function __construct(
        SessionManager $sessionManager
    ) {
        $this->coreSession = $sessionManager;    
    }

    /**
     * @param $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return mixed
    */
    public function afterCanOnepageCheckout(\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data $subject, $result)
    {
        //Here $this->coreSession->getVIEUserData() unable to fetch here

        if($result) {
            if($this->coreSession->getVIEUserData()) {
                return false;
            }
            return $result;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You want SID value in params, Right ?

Comment: @NagarajuK, https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/127617/3368

Comment: @SupravatM whether I want to use the customer session concept here?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya I am able to fetch the param value in the RewriteSID.php & able to set VIEUserData session variable but unable to fetch the value in the plugin file

Comment: Please use **SessionManagerInterface** in Plugin file and check once, because in your RewriteSID you used this

Comment: sure @KishanSavaliya let me check & get back to you shortly

Comment: @NagarajuK, can you use `Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;` instead of `Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager`

Comment: No Luck @SupravatM, krishnan still unable to fetch.

Comment: Did you run deployment commands after this changes ?

Comment: yes @KishanSavaliya compiled & flushed cache & given permissions

Comment: The scope of the custom router is in frontend & scope of the plugin which is using is frontend area. a plugin is calling fine but in the plugin, the session data is unable to fetch

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tgy9OmxPNiWFhX_qvbT8vRnmNfJh5a2s/view

Comment: In same file where you're setting data, are you able to get data there ? **Vendor/ModuleName/Controller/Router/RewriteSID.php**

Comment: Yes @KishanSavaliya after set data i am checking with log able to get the data in the same file

Comment: There is no need for you to create route file if you want to check something in plugin, you can inject request class and access SID in plugin as well.

Comment: Here we have used plugin concept  for displaying proceed to checkout button based on session variable

Comment: Hi @YashShah I need your suggestion here i.e when I use this match concept which is not triggering the first time but which is triggering from second time

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using sort_order 20 in your router declaration, try decreasing it to sortOrder 15. Since order 20 is used by URL Rewrites, it could be picking up a URL rewrite instead of your controller on the first visit. Such as redirecting http to https etc.

If that doesn't work, i would advice checking the following things.

1. Controller is actually firing on first load
2. Correct execution order (Controller then plugin)
3. Try a `controller_action_predispatch` event

Answer (score 0):

We have fixed the issue by creating and handling by **custom controller** in my custom module instead of the **custom router**.

Now we are providing the redirect URL to 3rd party system as mentioned below
 `http://magento2.com/vie/index/redirect/sid/322e00bfqm3g6rfpjumah3939n` instead of `http://magento2.com/?SID=322e00bfqm3g6rfpjumah3939n` so that 3rd party user will call this redirect controller.

From the controller, we are fetching unique id **sid** & processing further. So we are able to avoid the set **session-id** issues for the first time.

As well we have unset that session-id once after submitting the cart data to 3rd party on the checkout cart page.

Comment: does this solution work for session clear issue for 3ds redirection?

Comment: yes it is working @Sree