# Magento2: How to set custom session in controller?

Tags: magento2, session

How to set custom session in my controller ? I'm set the session in controller but I got an interceptor error in Magento2.

Comment: post question with your specfic codes (what ever you did) and also post error description(Which are you facing). So that we can investigate your problem very closely and may we help you quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1** : Create `Session.php` file in Model

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Model;
/**
 * Message session model
 */

class Session extends \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager
{
  protected $_session;
  protected $_coreUrl = null;
  protected $_configShare;
  protected $_urlFactory;
  protected $_eventManager;
  protected $response;
  protected $_sessionManager;
 
  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolverInterface $sidResolver,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface $sessionConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandlerInterface $saveHandler,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\ValidatorInterface $validator,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\StorageInterface $storage,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\Generic $session,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response
    ) {

        $this->_session = $session;
        $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
 
        parent::__construct(
            $request,
            $sidResolver,
            $sessionConfig,
            $saveHandler,
            $validator,
            $storage,
            $cookieManager,
            $cookieMetadataFactory,
            $appState
        );
        $this->response = $response;
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('sessionname_session_init', ['sessionname_session' => $this]);
    }  
}
```

**Step 2** : Inside Model/Session create `Storage.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Model\Session;

class Storage extends \Magento\Framework\Session\Storage
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Share $configShare
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param string $namespace
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        $namespace = 'sessionname',
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($namespace, $data);
    }
}
```

**Step 3** : Inside etc create `di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:frameworkSmiley SurprisedbjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    
    <type name="Vendor\Modulename\Model\Session">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="storage" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Modulename\Model\Session\Storage</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Step 4** : Inject Custom Session Class in Controller

```
    <?php 
namespace Vendor/Modulename/Controller/Index/index;

class index extends /Magento/Framework/App/Action/Action
{
    public function __construct(
      ......................
      \Vendor\Modulename\Model\Session $session,
      ......................
      array $data = []
    ) {
      $this->session = $session;
      parent::__construct($context,$data);
    }


    public function execute() {
        
        ................
        // Set Custom Session 
        $exampleArry = [
            'var1' => "first value",
            'var2' => "second value",
        ];
        $this->session->setExampleArry($exampleArry);
        
        // Get Custom Session
        $this->session->getExampleArry();

        // To get all session data : 
        $this->session->getData();


        ..................
    }
}
```

**Step 5** : Run this command

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush -q

Comment: thanks for ur answer,here i want to pass this session value to model .How can I do this?

Comment: Hi @supravat https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298536/magento-2-core-session-value-not-getting-in-the-custom-module can u suggest me on this

Comment: @Raji, Inject Session class in your Model and call  `$this->session->setExampleArry($exampleArry);` where you want. Don't forgat to compile your code.

Comment: ok sir , thank you.

Comment: @Raji, accept answer if its really help you. So that it could be help other also.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to set Customer Session:

1. You injection `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session` class to the constructor 
   function of the Controller.
2. Remove `generated` folder in magento source root by command: `rm -rf generated/*`
3. Run again.